# Find() in mongoDB C# driver with uuids doesn't work

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, uuid, guid

I'm trying to find a document in mongoDB by a uuid/guid, but even when converting the C# uuids to the standard uuids, it doesn't work. Using find() on other properties works fine.

A bit more detail about the uuids themselves: they're uuids of minecraft accounts, inserted by a plugin. I'm trying to query them from mognoDB with C# to make an api. I know the uuids stored are the new uuid format because that's what it returns in the binary data (4 is a standard uuid): [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCaW9.png)

I've tried the following:

```
public async Task<User> Get(Guid uuid) {
            BsonBinaryData binUuid = new BsonBinaryData(uuid, GuidRepresentation.Standard);
            return await users.Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("_id", binUuid)).FirstOrDefaultAsync<User>();
        }
```

My user model looks like this:

```
public class User {
        public Guid Id {get; set;}
        public string? data {get; set;}
        public string? lastKnownName {get; set;}
        public SkinBlob? lastKnownSkin {get; set;}
        public DateTime? lastOnline {get; set;}
        public DateTime? firstJoin {get; set;}
        public string? maskRank {get; set;}
        public string? maskName {get; set;}
        public SkinBlob? maskSkin {get; set;}
        public string? disguise {get; set;}
        public PermissionInfo? permissionInfo {get; set;}
    }
```

In mongoDB compass, this is what a user looks like:
[mongdoDB compass screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcUe3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In C# Mongodb driver you can only use BsonValue.

You can find a list of BsonValue type here
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/ObjectModel

My advice here would be to use string instead of Guid.
If you really want to use Guid then write BsonGuid class taking inspiration from another BsonValue type, for example BsonString

```
public class BsonString : BsonValue, IComparable<BsonString>, IEquatable<BsonString>
...
```

Comment: I have `return await users.Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("_id", new BsonString("8c0d6f65-f46c-4c1e-ac02-63785f140e50"))).FirstOrDefaultAsync<User>();` now (with that uuid being a uuid in the database for testing) but it's still not returning anything...

Comment: You need to change in your class "publig string Guid Id {get;set;}" to be sure this is a string and the MongoDB driver can match the Id type with the class type.

Comment: This code is working: var coll = cnx.GetDatabase("test").GetCollection<Test>("test");
            Test t3 = new Test() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), name = "Paul" };
            coll.InsertOne(t3);
            var t2 = coll.Find(_ => _.Id == t3.Id).FirstOrDefault();